# Is there a tool for managing apt repositories that allows multiple versions of the same package?

Tags: debian, apt, repository

I am currently using `reprepro` to manage a public repository for a small number of packages (source, and binaries for amd64 and arm64) across several different distributions. This is working smoothly so far as it goes, but I have had a request to keep old versions of packages around as well as the latest one - i.e., *system-genie 2.3* and *2.4* as well as *2.5*, and so forth - something which `reprepro` and the other tools I have investigated do not appear to permit.

Is there an apt repository management tool which can manage multiple versions of the same package (in the same distribution and of the same architecture)?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/445663/158442

Answer (score 2):

In a comment, muru linked to a Q&A with several recommendations, among which was [Aptly](https://www.aptly.info/).  I've used Aptly to manage a repository of Debian packages with older and newer versions of packages, all of which are available from the repo.

Aptly writes new packages to the repo's tree of directories and files, and also manages the repository index files to show which packages and versions are available from the repo.  `apt` reads the index files and decides which package file to fetch from the repo and install.